# How to instruct MS Visual C++ compiler to use an uninitialized __m512i register

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intrinsics, micro-optimization, avx512

How to instruct the Visual C++ compiler (1926) to use an uninitialized `__m512i` register. In the following code snippet a `not(or(A,B))` is calculated, the content of `dummy` is irrelevant.

```
__m512i dummy;
const __m512i n8 = _mm512_ternarylogic_epi64(dummy, A, B, 0x11);
```

Somehow the compiler assumes the register needs to have some content, (it does not), and an expensive and unnecessary memory reference is generated for `zmm0`:

```
62 F1 7E 48 6F 45 00 vmovdqu32   zmm0,zmmword ptr [rbp]  
62 F3 DD 48 25 C5 11 vpternlogq  zmm0,zmm4,zmm5,11h
```

ICC 19.0.1 understands the this situation and does not generate the `vmovdqu32`.

What have I tried: initializing `dummy` with 0 replaces the `vmovdqu32` with:

```
C5 F1 EF C9          vpxor       xmm1,xmm1,xmm1
```

This still gives an unnecessary instruction and a stall.

Thus the **question**: how to instruct the Visual C++ compiler to do the same as the Intel compiler? Just do not initialize the dummy register.

Comment: *and a stall.* - xor-zeroing is dependency breaking.  [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617).  It's literally as cheap as a NOP on current Intel CPUs, and avoids the risk of an output dependency coupling this dep chain into another one.  However, if you want to risk it, `_mm512_undefined_si512()` might work as the dummy arg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> and a stall

[xor-zeroing is dependency breaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).  It's also literally as cheap as a NOP on current Intel CPUs, and avoids the risk of an output dependency coupling this dep chain into another one.  It won't cause a stall (except indirectly, like from an I-cache miss), but it is a potential waste of one fused-domain uop of front-end throughput.

---

If `A` or `B` are dead after this, use one of them as the dummy input, like this

```
__m512i nor_A(__m512i A, __m512i B) {
    return _mm512_ternarylogic_epi64(A, A, B, 0x11);
}
```

When not inlined, so the input regs are dead afterward, and it has to return in the same reg it received `A` in, all 4 major x86 compilers make ideal code for this simple case.  (Some optimize the immediate to `5` instead of `0x11`, I guess using the first input.)

```
; MSVC 19.24 -O2 -arch:AVX512 -Gv    (vectorcall calling convention)
# gcc10/clang10/ICC19 -O3 -march=skylake-avx512
nor_A:
        vpternlogq      zmm0, zmm0, zmm1, 17
        ret
```

Or if you're using this in a loop, you could intentionally create a loop-carried dep chain by using the destination as the first input.  Declare the vector outside the loop.  If you're using ternlog inside a wrapper function, you'd need to pass a reference to the vector into that function to make this work.

---

If you want to risk a false dependency, **[`_mm512_undefined_epi32()`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX_512&text=undefined&expand=5983) is your best hope for what you want**.  It safely expresses what you want (an arbitrary register) while avoiding Undefined Behaviour from reading an uninitialized C variable.  (And no, IDK why Intel thought `epi32` would make more sense than `si512` like `_mm_undefined_si128()`.  There isn't a masked version of it!)

ICC compiles it to zero extra instructions.  Clang, GCC and MSVC do xor-zero a destination register, though, perhaps implementing it as `_mm512_setzero_si512` if they don't really support undefined inputs in their internals.  [**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAFZJpLegAyeWpgByxgEaZiIAMykADqgWE6rR6hibmln4BanR2Ds5Gbh7eSirRtAwEzMQEIcamForKmKpBGVkEsU6u7l6Kmdm5YQUK9RX2VQk1ngCUiqgGxMgcAORSnvbIhlgA1OKeOnhGRvYExPYAdAhz2OIADACCe4eS41TTWFTt6BAA%2BjcA4o4Aqjp33bOSAGxSn9NgYBcrrcbgBJRwAFWwNhuOgA8gBZAAKIJs2AASt0jncjGZOJI8NNaCQbsBaAZkMCcXiCftSNNsbj8dNpO9xAB2WQHabc6bETAEAa0aYAPwghzZOhZc054oAIkcxtY8FQFQcGdTCcT9pTGTS6eqmSzZhyjjzefzBfSloybgR3LQsgBPVioYB4ZA3TA%2BPCfbhium05l03YAD04nExnhl7PlB1V%2BwNBKJxBuBm0mCoOo1gcTzNZJq5PL5AuIQpu1rxtvtTpdbo9Xp9fvLVMkqfTlwc6E93s8kggvWmgfk01D4cj0bZscOavLus1KbT9kINye0izTJzs41RvZMrNufQxiMjulpqLFtLVpbVdLNdd7u7jYgh6WjoDdOHo4j0rNCsn8dzZM2yXAgV2kPtc03FsCR3At9jNNBaBaektyZWgAA5Zk8WUrxtO1b2IZ173rb1fQgDD3yDEcw2/KNf0Lbli0tDDTzjf8DmGXpWBAYYzGGUhTGGXZ%2BNQHidDkORpgUfpBkwD5PE4fiCB44Tul6ABrLxuHWbg8TMXtPk8NldjZMw2Usbjhm4fijC4XZdgElSRJ4/iFBABzlKEzjSDgWAYCgfyICQNAjG9dgyAoCAQrCmpgE4XZOFIS5WHwtyIBcJzSBcewnR4xTSBCowtAIWFaFYR1MqwIwRGAdhKrwPkSgAN0wNyvKsENigMO08v4lZlEy1g8BcYgnT0LBetIVZFl63oaHoJg2A4Hh%2BEEYRRBQCSZCEYa3MgXpUB8NI2oAWhDZBphO2FPEu6rBi2bCFHU51mHUzATuYJqQ0ZS6AHU2FYVyihKDQIGsRpTES6xKniRJBEiQI6Ah%2BH/ER2gYeqDxEpSYo0jKBp9DyQQcZB9JWgxzosbqcpkex8n2lhmoIz6AYhi4LieL4xz2tE4YQ3Qz4Tt9aZgGQC74vWThpggXBCBIeTEumPRQrwcKFfecSZDkJSnLU0hNLMBzLOs0hbMN7nhNIXnXPcqbdZ8wLgtQFXwvIShotVmp3WQTgAE5EuS1LKAy9rsodQjJsK4rSvKyrMGq0Q6va/BGrUFq2stzBOuQbqRny/rLMtoaRrGjA86UtZbOGRS5roRgWDqlaBF4daxC2%2BRi72/sraOoJTvOy7rturJkAe2Unpet6Pq%2Bn6Tv%2B1hAcKVIgk0bRaasbQKbhxKEbSdfd6CLemaX3HSladeSbx%2Bm4kx4nz8JsI6fKI%2Bsd6aTWeWjneP4wTLd5/nBbC29tMP26xdiS2lrLIgxAFZ0mVjFGBYxuAa3bjrLyesECYGYFgDw3djY2XMA5X%2Bzlhg2w8rrDShChA8U8D/TK1s7boIdvAXyiAUDOwQW7KKHDPYeEmDVeK9kkqqyDulTKYdcrV34lHegMcKrJ3jjVJOlsU6n3TplLOXUepSPIPQAa7Vi6jUIuNcuU1K6zSSnXRajdeACAsjVTaWttqd3gAdXudB%2B4XSujdE6d1R5zHHs9YQU9PrfTxH9AGQNl6g3Bg/SGG9bAM1vjvVGe84koyiIfJJlNibAyvjTdJ2M8ln2ftk7e1MCahHiS0UpN8cnM3frJdm1Dv4WxIQAoW3Bpj8NECA8B/TIH4GgbApWPC1ZjEkCgpx0g0GqV6Jg7BNRu4GyNjxE2ZsiH0JcooW2nlVLMNgE7F27guEe3CiAJqyAfA%2BBuE1P2NxJDcBuCGX0wiUruDSiHS2EiI46JkSVMq8iVGKMTiMFRDU1GtQ0dnXOk0C6DWGkYx0JjJrTSrjXSxC0G7LVsbUVujjZDON2q4nux0eJXUkJde4TVLojyQPsAAagADUZFE0%2BMS16FISS/DJaN96pKyXU8pl8SmVKJkU6JZNakdGFffKpd9pWM1fizJpzNLJc2IVbHiLyulGAUJc6YdzfbrEeYMuWiCTiK3gbw%2BSPQlaoMYXM0gCycGUC/usqhmqGFuXIegyh5tLK0LaVq0hjrOKUM%2BGYdYZh0Jsm4J8NknhPiSF9o87wllJAEMEcGhhezw0tMzTm7Zea9YtWIAEDQ3AgA%3D)

I also included versions with actual UB; ICC and clang do what you wanted there, picking `zmm0` as the dummy input.

```
__m512i nor_undef(__m512i A, __m512i B) {
    return _mm512_ternarylogic_epi64(_mm512_undefined_epi32(), A, B, 0x11);
}
```

MSVC 19.24 `-O2 -arch:AVX512 -Gv` - not great, but basically fine, so the same source can compile to what you want for ICC without being terrible anywhere.

```
__m512i nor_undef(__m512i,__m512i) PROC             ; nor_undef, COMDAT
    vpxor   xmm2, xmm2, xmm2
    vpternlogq zmm2, zmm0, zmm1, 17
    vmovdqu32 zmm0, zmm2
    ret     0
```

GCC 10.1:

```
nor_undef:
    vmovdqa64       zmm2, zmm0
    vpxor   xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
    vpternlogq      zmm0, zmm2, zmm1, 17
    ret
```

Clang 10.0

```
nor_undef:
    vpxor   xmm2, xmm2, xmm2
    vpternlogq      zmm0, zmm2, zmm1, 5
    ret
```

ICC 19.0.1

```
nor_undef:
    vpternlogq zmm0, zmm2, zmm1, 5                          #15.12
    ret                                                     #15.12
```

Comment: These are useful experiments, thank you! 

If someone reading this does know how to instruct (or coerce) MSVC to honour the _mm_undefined_si128() and generate no instruction; please add a new answer.